# PYTHON: How to (function, tuples and output)

Tags: python, function, tuples

I'm still quite new to programming and I've been trying to figure out how to create a function that returns (in this case) three elements like strings and print them out in separate lines. For example:

`tuple = ("name", "name", "name")`

should end up looking like this:

```
name

name

name
```

Don't know if it makes sense? I know how to do it with an ordinary for loop, but can't figure it out with a function.

Comment: What should the function's input/output? If you want to take a tuple and print it, make the tuple as an argument and write that loop inside the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "\n\n" to concatenate strings in your function, like:

```
def print_strings(t):
    res = "\n\n".join(t)
    return res
test_values = ("name", "name", "name")
result = print_strings(test_values)
print(result)
```

By the way, keywords(like tuple) should not be used to declare variables, otherwise that keyword will lose its original function

Answer (score 0):

You could just iterate the tuple in your function, e.g.

```py
tuple = ("name", "name", "name")
for t in tuple:
    print(t)
```